Firebase Messaging v1 : static badge value in Flutter
In my Flutter app, I migrated to Firebase Messaging v1 to manage notifications. I'm using the new syntax of the requests according to the documentation :
{
  "message": {
    "android": {
      "priority": "HIGH",
      "notification": {
        "notification_count": 1
      }
    },
    "token": "$token",
    "notification": {
      "title": "title_value",
      "body": "body_value"
    },
    "data": {
      "title": "title_value",
      "message": "body_value"
    }
  }
}

The problem is on iOS, there's no badge on the app icon displaying that a notification arrived.
After researches, I found that I had to add this in the body :
 "apns": {
      "payload": {
        "aps": {
          "badge": 1
        }
      }
    }

Now there's the badge displayed "1" on the app icon when the notification is triggered but there are 2 major issues :

The badge "1" is always displayed on the app icon, no matter if I clicked on the notification alert or opened the app. I even closed the app on the background and the badge is still here
Since I specified the number of the badge, it's a constant value. Meaning that if I send 10 notifications with "badge": 1 in the request, it will always display "1" in the value of the badge. It doesn't increment all the notifications and display the result.

Any solutions ?
